# Using Opentelemetry to write logs for Python

Tags: python, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing, observability, distributedlog

We are using Python and we want to use Opentelemetry for logs.
I see that Logs for Python are not supported yet(https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/python/) and for C++/.NET it is in beta/experimental. My question is will it make any sense to wrap the .NET with Python and use it?
My main concern is log generation and not collection (as the collection is external to the app and I can use any PL).
Any tech limitation doing it? any compatibility issues that are predicted in the future?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python also has an experimental support for logging SDK. The linked status is old and not updated. Here is an example illustrating the sample usage of logging SDK with OTLP collector https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/logs/README.html.